# Usb device cannot be detected

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a sandisk ultra usb 3.0 flash disk that I have been using to watch movies on my television. Recently, when the I plug the flash disk into the tv usb port, it starts playing a movie and then suddenly comes up with an error usb device cannot be found or audio format not supported.

I have tried formatting the flash as I read in some post, I have also tried to format it in NTFS and checked the flash drive for badblocks using linux and the device does not have any bad sectors and nothing seems to be working. I have also done a factory reset on the television and the problem still persists. With another flash disk there are no problems when plugged in to the tv usb port.

what can I do to solve this problem?